# Split List string and create dictionary

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
lst= ['1 5','1 12','1 55','2 95', '2 66', '3 45',...]
```

As you can see each item consists of 2 numbers, second number is at most 4 characters long and they are separated by space.

I want to transfer that into dictionary like this

```
dct={1:{'doc0005','doc0012','doc0055'},2:{'doc0095','doc0066'},3:{'doc0045'},...}
```

each value item should be 7 characters long: `'doc'+someZeros+'second number` from the list item, where someZeros are extra 0 characters to make value 7 characters long. And first number will be key of a dictionary

I was trying to split each item of a list and via loop adding it into dictionary, but i'm got confused

Comment: So many wonderful solutions. I think there is a long way till I learn this all. Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to do with a (default)dictionary of sets.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
for l in lst:
     k, v = l.split()
     d[k].add(f'doc{int(v):04d}')  # "doc{:04d}".format(int(v))

print(d)
defaultdict(set,
            {'1': {'doc0005', 'doc0012', 'doc0055'},
             '2': {'doc0066', 'doc0095'},
             '3': {'doc0045'}})
```

If you'd prefer a plain dictionary, either `dict`ify the result above, or use a slightly different (less efficient solution) using `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = {}
for l in lst:
    k, v = l.split()
    d.setdefault(k, set()).add(f'doc{int(v):04d}')  # "doc{:04d}".format(int(v))

print(d)
{'1': {'doc0005', 'doc0012', 'doc0055'},
 '2': {'doc0066', 'doc0095'},
 '3': {'doc0045'}}
```

Comment: Then `print(dict(d))` for a dict

Comment: And replace f-strings to something else ifversion < python 3.6

Comment: @U9-Forward, Or upgrade to 3.6+ :). Also `defaultdict` *is* a `dict`.

Comment: You can replace `d[k].add(f'doc{int(v):04d}')` with `d[k].add('doc{:04d}'.format(int(v)))` if you don't want to use f-strings. But I personally think f-strings are more pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

Or easy `setdefault`:

```
d={}
for i in l:
    d.setdefault(i.split()[0],set()).add('doc%04d' % int(i.split()[1]))
print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a solution without imports:

```
lst= ['1 5','1 12','1 55','2 95', '2 66', '3 45']

result = {}

for i in lst:
    k, v = i.split()
    k = int(k)
    v = 'doc{}'.format(v.zfill(4))
    if k in result:
        result[k].add(v)
    else:
        result[k] = {v}

print(result)
#{1: {'doc0005', 'doc0012', 'doc0055'}, 2: {'doc0095', 'doc0066'}, 3: {'doc0045'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list is ordered by the key part of each string, you can use `groupby` with O(*n*) complexity:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = ['1 5','1 12','1 55','2 95', '2 66', '3 45']
split = [list(map(int, item.split())) for item in lst]
grouper = groupby(split, key=itemgetter(0))

res = {i: {f'doc{x[1]:04d}' for x in j} for i, j in grouper}

# {1: {'doc0005', 'doc0012', 'doc0055'},
#  2: {'doc0066', 'doc0095'},
#  3: {'doc0045'}}
```

If your input is not ordered, you will need to sort first, which will be expensive. In this case, you can consider `collections.defaultdict` with `set` as per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508033/9209546).

Comment: I personally like/prefer groupby because that's an SQL idiom I like to use when thinking of how to solve problems,... but sometimes people prefer the simpler stuff. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just with a loop

```
d = {}
for i in lst:
    if i.split()[0] not in d:
        d[i.split()[0]] = 'doc{}'.format((i.split()[1]).zfill(4))    
    elif i.split()[0] in d:
        d[i.split()[0]] += ', doc{}'.format(i.split()[1].zfill(4))
```

> ```
> {'1': 'doc0005, doc0012, doc0055', '2': 'doc0095, doc0066', '3': 'doc0045'}
> ```